# FFmpeg 5.0 vs 3.4 performance

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, video-quality, h.264

I was trying to compare ffmpeg 5.0 vs version 3.4.6 in how much performance improvements I would get while transcoding a simple 720p video into a H264 video. On my laptop, I noticed around 5-10% improvement in the total execution time when using the updated version.

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.webm -r 30 -vf eq=gamma=.95:saturation=1.1,scale=w=960:h=540:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -crf 25 -tune film -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -async 1 -movflags +faststart -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 output.mp4
```

Should I really expect a performance improvement when using this updated version? And are there any other flags or ways I can add to improve performance or quality even more?